# Why does lateral force act on front wheels when rear wheels are locked?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

While I was reading  up on vehicular dynamics, I came across a point that when rear wheels are locked, lateral force acts on the front wheels.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score -1):

Wheels are designed to roll: they have very little resistance to motion perpendicular to the axle, but a lot of resistance to motion parallel to it.  If a wheel doesn't roll, but must instead slide, it moves with approximately equal resistance in any direction.  The direction of the force exerted by the ground on locked rear wheels is more or less exactly opposite to the direction the wheels are sliding. So the rear wheels are of no help in determining where the vehicle goes--they just act to slow it down. The force on the front wheels (assuming they are rolling freely and not braked or driven) is lateral (parallel to the axis of the wheel). I think this is what is meant--normally, there are lateral forces on all the wheels of a car traversing a curve.  If the rear wheels lock, the only remaining lateral forces are on the front wheels.

Comment: -1 If the car is cornering, why are there lateral forces on unlocked wheels but not on locked wheels? The lateral forces would still be parallel to the axle. Why the difference?

Comment: Because, as stated, the force on locked wheels is opposite to the direction they're sliding, not in general parallel to the axel.  Have you ever seen a car going around  a corner with locked rear wheels?  Does it track with the rear wheels directly behind the front ones?  No, the back of the car swings out.  The rear wheels slide at an angle, and the force the road exerts on them is decidedly not parallel to the axle.  Kindly retract your -1.